# cheetah parsing error trying to change cheetahVarStartToken

Tags: python, templates, cheetah

I am writing a cheetah template and I want to change the cheetahVarStartToken so that I can use the $ for javascript libraries in that section of code however when I run the template I am getting this error

> ConfigParser.ParsingError: File contains parsing errors: 
>       [line  2]: u'\t\t\t cheetahVarStartToken = "%"\n'

here is my code

```
#compiler-settings
cheetahVarStartToken = "%"
#end compiler-settings

  <script>
   //My javascript code
  </script>

#compiler-settings reset
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That assignment must start in the first column, so remove the whitespace at the front of `cheetahVarStartToken`:

This works:

```
cheetahVarStartToken = "%"
```

This blows up:

```
 cheetahVarStartToken = "%"

 ConfigParser.ParsingError: File contains parsing errors: <???>
     [line  2]: ' cheetahVarStartToken = "%"\n'
```